# The following code has been giving me the same output for a long time

Tags: python-3.x, praw

I have been writing some code with PRAW. I want the following to give the top posts each day.But it has been returning the same ids even though new posts are submitted each day and different posts are at the top. What should I do?

```
import praw  
reddit=praw.Reddit(client_id='id',
               client_secret='secret',password='password',
               user_agent='agent',username='username')


top_funny=subreddit.top(limit=1)
for submission in top_funny:
    print(submission)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default `subreddit.top()` returns the top of all time. You can change this by using the `time_filter` parameter and specify any of the following: hour, day, week, month, year, all.

ex:

```
subreddit.top("day", limit=1)
```

will return the top submission from today.

Answer (score 0):

As LampToast said, you should use the time_filter.

Arguments for .top() are listed in the docs:

`Parameters:  time_filter – Can be one of: all, day, hour, month, week, year (default: all).`

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code_overview/models/multireddit.html#praw.models.Multireddit.top